# Can we run flutter app on Windows7 and Windows8?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

We are planning to develop a cross platform app using flutter. There were few users who are still using Windows7 and Windows8 machines. Can we run flutter app on Windows7 and Windows8 machines? I couldn’t find exact answer for this anywhere. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In this website you can find the answer [Flutter-Supported deployment platforms](https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/supported-platforms)
.
Platform: Windows
Supported: 10
Best effort: 7, 8, and 11
Unsupported: Vista-, any 32-bit

I hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Actually I already saw that. But my query here is I'm looking for exact answer. I mean whether it will be possible to run on Windows7 and Windows8 or not. Because in that link, its saying "Best Effort". So, I did not understand whether it means supported or not. Does that mean we need to do some tweaks to make it supported?

Comment: I don't know. I am sorry.